# stop loops with hasNext() condition

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
(Scanner Input=new Scanner(System.in))
```

I have a `while` loop in my program with `Input.hasNext()` condition.
I want to read a line with scanner without `Input.nextLine();` because i want to use the strings and integers in that line with `.next()` & `.nextInt()` ,how can i break the `while` loop after reading one line, or how can I break the while loop with entering newline character?

```
while (Input.hasNext()) {
    if (Input.hasNextFloat()) {
      Grade=Input.nextFloat();
      P.setGrades(Grade);
      j=0;k=1;
      continue;
    }
    if (k==1) {
      P.getGPA();
      P=new Person();
      k=0;
    }
    if (j==1) {
      P.setLastName(Input.next());
      continue;
    }
    P.setFirstName(Input.next());
    i++;
    j=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only want 1 line read in 1 line and then parse the line

```
String line = Input.nextLine();
Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);//Scanner can also work on a String instead of a InputStream
while(lineScanner .hasNext()){
    if(lineScanner .hasNextFloat()){
      Grade=lineScanner .nextFloat();
      P.setGrades(Grade);
      j=0;k=1;
      continue;}
    if(k==1){
      P.getGPA();
      P=new Person();
      k=0;}
    if(j==1){
      P.setLastName(lineScanner .next());
      continue;}
    P.setFirstName(lineScanner .next());
    i++;
    j=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test for the condition(s) you want and use `break` to end the loop.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, I'd say that you can't use Scanner in the loop test. It just skips over newlines as white space and waits for something else. Instead, wrap System.in in a BufferedReader and use `readLine` to get the next user line. If the line is empty (zero length), then you can break out of the loop; otherwise, you can wrap the line in a Scanner to use Scanner's parsing methods for that line.

Comment: its up to user ,i cant use break.i want a way to make false Input.hasNext() condition with entering newline character

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
boolean b=true;
while (Input.hasNext() && b) {
    if (Input.hasNextFloat()) {
      Grade=Input.nextFloat();
      P.setGrades(Grade);
      j=0;k=1;
    } else {
        String content=Input.next();
        if (content.equals("")) {
            b=false;
        } else {
            if (k==1) {
              P.getGPA();
              P=new Person();
              k=0;
            }
            if (j==1) {
              P.setLastName(content);
              continue;
            }
            P.setFirstName(content);
            i++;
            j=1;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really used to the Scanner class, but I assume next() returns an empty string if newline is entered.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exit of while, put return; or if you want go to the next iteration of cycle
, put continue;